# Setting up Netdata -> Consul -> Prometheus Stack

Tags: prometheus, consul, netdata

According to the document:
https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/Netdata,-Prometheus,-and-Grafana-Stack

We can use Consul as the registry where all the Netdata agents will be registering and later Prometheus will scrape the Consul registry to get the registered endpoints and scrap the data out.

I tried looking for documents to set it up, but I was unable to find it, is there any document on setting up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to register the netdata instances in Consul. if you're running netdata in Docker containers you can use something like https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator for zero effort registration, if not, use service definition files or Consul's catalog API.

Here's an example for scraping Consul services with Prometheus - https://www.robustperception.io/finding-consul-services-to-monitor-with-prometheus/

Answer (score 0):

You can now drop Prometheus and query/visualize aggregated metrics right from the Netdata Cloud hose using the [new and official Netdata plugin for Grafana](https://www.netdata.cloud/blog/introducing-netdata-source-plugin-for-grafana/).

I have seen somewhere that Netdata will release official support for Consul.